# Gravitational potential energy on the Earth's surface

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth, planets, approximations

We assume that gravitational potential energy at a height $h$ from the Earth's surface is $mgh$. Is that accurate or only approximately correct ?

---

Here is my approach.

On the surface of the Earth, 
$U_s = -\dfrac{GMm}{R}\tag*{}$
($R$ is the radius of the Earth)

At a height from the Earth's surface,
$U_h=-\dfrac{GMm}{R+h}\tag*{}$

When we take the difference, we can find that 
$U_h-U_s =-\dfrac{GMm}{R} \left(\dfrac{h}{R+h}\right)\tag*{}$
(If I haven't made any miscalculations)

What can I say from this?

Comment: It's only approximate.

Comment: As an aside, you have made a miscalculation. In particular, you have a sign error. This is a minor issue. More importantly, this is a question that has already been asked.

Comment: @SkyWalker - well reasoned, - can you now prove that $mgh$ is reasonable if h<<R?

Comment: We also assume that the potential in the $h=0$ plane is constant--but that too is an approximation.